# How to add a Tilemap to a prefab?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a `Bomb` prefab that gets dinamically added to the center of a 2D tile on keypress via a `BombSpawner` script. When the bomb explodes, I want it to affect multiple tiles in my `Ground` tilemap.

The explosion is inside the `BombController` script which is part of my `Bomb` prefab. I tried accessing the tilemap by adding it manually to the prefab:

```
public Tilemap tilemap;
```

But it doesn't work. I can only drag and drop the tilemap to the `Bomb` when it's in the scene, not to the prefab.

Is there a way to access the `Ground` tilemap inside the `BombController` script?

Comment: Assign a tilemap to Bombspwaner script and then when you spawn the bomb assign that tilemap object to the property  ```BombCollider.tilemap``` script.

Comment: Thanks @Ankit that's what I ended up doing. You can post it as an answer. `bombObject.GetComponent<BombController> ().tilemap = tilemap;`

Comment: I posted my answer with bit of an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, This is what is normal in unity when you are working with prefabs. You can only assign components/scripts anywhere in prefab if that component/script is a part of the prefab itself.

If component/script is in your scene hierarchy but not in the prefab. In your case, it was `Tilemap` object. which was in your scene hierarchy but was not the part of your prefab. Even if you edit the prefab directly in the scene view(Don't get confused with prefab editor which looks as same as scene view). and save the prefab the `BombController.tilemap` will always be null(None). Something Like

[image: No assignment in Inspector]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried importing this library from unity 
**using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;**
and then do that variable
**public Tilemap tilemap;**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3NSh.png)

Comment: Yep, but the problem is that I can't attach a tilemap to a prefab, so I ended up with @Ankit's solution of assigned the tilemap after instantiating the bomb object.